# Angular <a href> links - odd behaviour

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

Folks I have real odd situation that doesn't seem to make sense to me at all. Here's my setup:

```
<html ng-app="mainApp">
    <head>blah</head>
<body>
    <header ng-controller="headerCntrl">
        <a href="#/profile">Profile</a>
    </header>
<blah>
<main ng-view></main>
<footer />
</body></html>
```

The header has it's own controller, then I use ngRoute to define various paths, including the profile:

```
.when('/profile', {
    templateUrl: 'views/profile.html',
    controller: 'profileController'
})
```

For some reason, clicking in the a href link in the header does nothing. No error, no activity. It does show the correct URL when you hover over the link, and, right-clicking and opening in new tab DOES work just fine.

Why does a normal left click not work? Bearing in mind that either:

- Typing that route in directly into address bar &
- Right click - open in new window

both work, what's stopping angular from loading that view into the  div?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is that you do not specify  [base url](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp). Try it.

Comment: Hi Vitalii, even replacing the href with an absolute link doesn't change the behaviour.

Comment: There are a lot of pitfalls that can lead to the problem. Without code it hard to say where you are. I can advise to try create simple app from guide to find the issue
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location